# python ttk treeview string values becomes long

Tags: python, treeview, ttk

I'm trying to store phone numbers in ttk treeview rows. I assign values as

```
phone_num="+123456789"
tree.insert(parent, 'end',text=p, values=(phone_num,),open=False)
```

But when I access it, it returns 123456789L

It is casting it to long. Is there any way I can get it as string "+12345678"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you need an option, such like below:

```
tree.insert(parent, 'end',text=p, values=(phone_num,),open=False,options="values")
```